# Array_walk value not showing

Tags: php, arrays

Having problem on getting the highlights_description. I want to echo the highlights_title and highlights_decription. This is the array

```
{
  "highlights_title": [
    "Quiet Neighbourhood",
    "Fabulous views",
    "Great local community",
    "Large play center in yard"
  ],
  "highlights_description": [
    "Enjoy tranquil and relaxed atmosphere of the place",
    "Get yourself surrounded by the stunning view opening",
    "You will be delighted by the fantastic local community",
    "Your kids will be happy having all these things around"
  ]
}
```

This is my code where it only shows highlightstitle only. how to echo both highlightstitle and highlightsdescription

```
$data = "{"title":"Property Highlights","description":"Extensive upgrades and thorough maintenance have kept this home in prime condition. Hardwood floors and new carpets create a very comfortable living space.","content":"{\"highlights_title\":[\"Quiet Neighbourhood\",\"Fabulous views\",\"Great local community\",\"Large play center in yard\"],\"highlights_description\":[\"Enjoy tranquil and relaxed atmosphere of the place\",\"Get yourself surrounded by the stunning view opening\",\"You will be delighted by the fantastic local community\",\"Your kids will be happy having all these things around\"]}","module_tag":"div","bootstrap_size":"0","header_tag":"h3","header_class":"","style":"0"}"

$highlights = json_decode($data, true);

if(!empty($highlights)){
    $content = $highlights['highlight_stitle'];
    array_walk($content, function($value){
        echo $value .'<br/>';
    });
}
```

Comment: `highlight_stitle` should be `highlights_title`.

Comment: You can use `implode` instead of `array_walk`, `echo implode(',',$highlights['highlights_title'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scan both arrays together by such foreach

```
if(!empty($highlights)) {
     foreach(array_map(null, $highlights['highlights_title'], $highlights['highlights_description']) 
              as list($title, $desc)) {
          echo $title.'\t'.$desc."<\br>\n";
     }
}
```

[**demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4c051ee59f8e28acc23d5143cba155c05cab4a5a)

Answer (score 0):

You have second json_encode for content so :

```
$data = '{"title":"Property Highlights","description":"Extensive upgrades and thorough maintenance have kept this home in prime condition. Hardwood floors and new carpets create a very comfortable living space.","content":"{\"highlights_title\":[\"Quiet Neighbourhood\",\"Fabulous views\",\"Great local community\",\"Large play center in yard\"],\"highlights_description\":[\"Enjoy tranquil and relaxed atmosphere of the place\",\"Get yourself surrounded by the stunning view opening\",\"You will be delighted by the fantastic local community\",\"Your kids will be happy having all these things around\"]}","module_tag":"div","bootstrap_size":"0","header_tag":"h3","header_class":"","style":"0"}';
$highlights = json_decode($data, true);
var_dump($highlights);
if (!empty($highlights)) {
    $content = json_decode($highlights["content"], true);
    foreach($content as $subcontent){
       foreach($subcontent as $value){
          echo $value . "<br/>";
       }
    }    
}
```

Comment: @MartinDimitrov you are working directly with $data["content"];

Comment: Try the code that he provides

Comment: @MartinDimitrov he can't access it because it's a string not an array, I think that is the problem, don't know how my answer is "not needed" in that case. When the typo is fixed I'll update my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197504/discussion-between-angel-bonev-and-martin-dimitrov).